# Decay of Thorium 233 to Protactinium 233 and then to Uranium 233

Tags: nuclear-physics

Reference: minutes 2:50 to 3:15 in the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Km6kqykX900&t=170s

I don't understand how the atomic number goes up by 1 in two decay steps. Is there a neutron decay in both the stages or is something more complicated going on?

Answer (score 2):

Both decay steps
$$^{233}_{\;90}\text{Th} \to\ ^{233}_{\;91}\text{Pa} + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e$$
$$^{233}_{\;91}\text{Pa} \to\ ^{233}_{\;92}\text{U}  + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e$$
are [$\beta^-$ decays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2%E2%88%92_decay).

That means in each step a neutron changes into a proton
(and an electron and an antineutrino).
$$n \to p + e^- + \bar{\nu}_e$$
Since a proton is created, the atomic number goes up by $1$.